# Blank pages with horizontal line and header

Tags: page-breaking, blank-page

I am writing my thesis paper in LaTeX. I wrote the main program like below, but whenever I compile the .tex file one extra blank page is added after every chapter, and it doesn't take into account if the next page is odd or even to add this extra one. I can't figure out why is it happening. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,spanish]{report}


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[dvips,pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[smaller,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[round,comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 



% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document customization
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{white}

\hoffset=-1in 
\marginparwidth=0in
\marginparsep=0in
\marginparpush=0in
\evensidemargin=2.23in
\oddsidemargin=0.98in
\textwidth=5.40in 


\voffset=-0.5in
\topmargin=0in
\headheight=20pt
\headsep=12pt
\textheight=7.8in
\footskip=30pt

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\linespread{1.0}
\sloppy
\pagenumbering{roman}


\addto\captionsspanish{
    \def\bibname{Referencias}
    \def\tablename{Tabla}
    \def\listtablename{\'Indice de Tablas}
    \def\appendixname{Anexo}
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Main document body
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


% Index
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{empty}

% Intro
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\include{Intro}

% Chapter 1
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Capt1}

% Chapter 2
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\include{Capt2}

\end{document}
```

And, as an example, the `Cap1.tex` looks like this:

```
\chapter{Aerosoles atmosféricos}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
\emph{En este capítulo ... }
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\rightmark}}}


\section{Introducción}
Los aerosoles atmosféricos son.... 

\section{Tipos de aerosoles}
....

\subsubsection{Clasificación climática}
Los tipos de aerosoles ...
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To remove the blank pages, change the `openright` for you documentclass to `openany`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I already tried that, it still gets the same extra page at the end of each chapter =(

Comment: What's inside the `Cap*.tex` files being `\included`?

Comment: `\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
\emph{text...}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\slshape{\rightmark}}}

%\cleardoublepage
%\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Introducción}
text...
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}`

Comment: Those are the code lines inside the `Cap*.tex`. _Text..._ means the text writen inside.

Comment: @Sara: What do you think, `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` does? ;-) I believe, that's the cause of your problem... Remove them in just one file, say `Cap1.tex` and recompile.

Comment: @Christian You mean the last line inside of the code inside `Cap*.tex`, don't you? I did it already, but there is no difference. I am still getting a blank page with the header and an horizontal line. The text of the chapter ends in page 14, then I get page 15 as the blank page with the header, then page 16 is also in blank so that the next chapter starts in page 17. I have no idea why it does this..

Comment: Unrelated but you can't do this `\usepackage[dvips,pdftex]{graphicx}` pick one or the other (it's usually best not to give an option at all, the system is usually set up to choose the correct option automatically)

Comment: @Sara If the `\clearpage` in your included files make no difference then they should go (they definitely look wrong) but in general we can't debug files that we can not see, try to make a small self contained complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: @david I have just included an example of the `Cap1.tex`file in the question on top. Hope it makes it easier to look at the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Your included file ends with a `\cleardoublepage`, remove that and change the `openright` option as indicated before.  By the way, are the lines `-------------` in your source really intended not to be commented out with `%`?

Comment: Not really as it still refers to things we have not got, the example should be self contained so that people can run it as posted, and such that it demonstrates the problem, it would be more helpful without the other chapters without the `------------` lines (are they your actual problem?) and without the bibliography etc.

Comment: the "rule" after Índice general is from your line of `-` here: ` % Index
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents`

Comment: That is the problem, if I comment out your `----` lines the chapter opens as expected

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` causes your problem.

Comment: That's right, I just realized. What a silly thing... Thank you all!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by code not posted